# Update resx from DB in runtime xamarin c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

Is there a way to update RESX files from a database when the RESX files are embedded resources?

I know you can read them, but I can't find a way to write or update the file.

I have tried this from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/work-with-resx-files-programmatically

Hope some of you know the answer.

Comment: No.  Android and iOS bundles are signed at build time and can't be written to at runtime.

Comment: You can't achieve that but you can copy it to the local storage and then use the local file as data source.